# Get all "grand"-Children of a given Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

im trying to learn python/django at the moment and came across the following problem.
Let's say i have 3 models:

```
Model Category(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length64)

Model Subcategory(models.Model)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name        = models.Charfield(max_length64)

Model Animal(models.Model)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length64)
```

Now, for example, if someone searches for a category, i want to have all the animals that are in any of the subcategories of the given main category. ( Hope its not too complicated)

So now my question is what is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your logic and nesting needs get more complex you should look into django-mptt for storing this type of data.  A couple tiers is nothing to manage, but once you start getting deeper it's better to have a more robust system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a query like:

```
animals = Animal.objects.filter(subcategory__category__id=category_id)
```

OR, If you have access to the category object,

```
animals = Animal.objects.filter(subcategory__category=category)
```

Please note that model object definition is `class <ClassName>` and not `Model <ClassName>`
Example:
`Model Animal` should be `class Animal`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with the following queryset:

```
animals = Animal.objects.filter(subcategory__category=category)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats exactly what i was searching for!